# Controlling an Arduino with Python

Tags: python, arduino, integration

I'm creating facial recognition software that needs to activate a motor when a face is detected. Currently, I have the code in the Arduino IDE that controls the servo motor, and I have the facial recognition software in Visual Studio using OpenCV (built in python) that prints out a message when a face is found. I want to be pointed in the right direction on how to control an arduino with python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can run facial recognition software on Arduino as it is used only for controlling some peripheral like LEDs and motors.

I think Raspberry Pi is better choice for you as RPi is more efficient microcomputer with own OS. You can plug in special RPi camera to RPi  for facial recognition. You can control motor with RPi as well.
In case you need Arduino for controlling motor you can plug Arduino to RPi.